# Windows 10 stuck on Automatic Repair says missing driver

Tags: boot, laptop-repair

my hp laptop is stuck on automatic repair loop with the following error:

```
The operation system couldn't be loaded because a critical system driver is missing or contains errors.

file \windows\system32\drivers\nldrv.sys
Error code: 0xc0000359`
```

it won't boot into safe mode or any other mode. have tried using installation media to repair the system but to no avail.

any help?!

Comment: You are likely going to be required to reinstall windows.

Comment: it's not letting me do the reinstallation

Comment: I mean, boot from install medium, run setup, wipe C partition, create new, and install.

Comment: thanks a lot, but after googling for the solution i found this to work. http://www.screwloose.com.au/windows-10-bootrec-the-requested-system-device-cannot-be-found

Comment: Ah. Well, the information in your question wasn't clear enough to think that would be the solution. But feel free to write an answer for your question so you can mark it as answered in 2 days and people know you no longer need any help. :)

Comment: 0xc0000359 = STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_WIN_32 The specified image file did not have the correct format, t appears to be a 32-bit Windows image. looks like you have a 64bit windows and installed a 32bit driver. nldrv.sys = netlimiter driver.

Answer (score -1):

I just booted with the install media to new install, then repair,and the command prompt, and renamed nldrv.sys, rebooted, and problem was gone.
This is a netlimiter file.